# svnadmin: SQLite is required to be compiled and run in thread-safe mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-server, svn, sqlite

I've used `apt-get` to install Subversion and SQLite on my Ubuntu VPS, however, I'm getting this error when I try to use `svn`:

`svnadmin: SQLite is required to be compiled and run in thread-safe mode`

Does anyone know why this might be happening? I originally tried to compile sqlite and subversion from source before switching to the ubuntu packages - could this be the issue perhaps?

Comment: Show us the output of "ldd $(which svnadmin)", please.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The output of `ldd $(which svnadmin) | grep sqlite` is
`libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x0062d000)`.

`/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0` is a symlink to `libsqlite3.so.0.8.6` and this file was installed via `apt-get` as part of the "sqlite"-package.

The problem was that, as svn complained, my version of `libsqlite3.so` was not thread-safe. So I replaced it with the version from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html. This actually worked.